# Can I set up one background image per scene?

Tags: camera, image

Thanks for click my question.

I got some layout images from my 2D storyboard team.
and i want set up that image per multiple scene in one blend file.

But.. the background image always works across all scenes.

So for me, blender's Background Image function looks useful only for single scene or modeling.

The same is true for ambient occlusion or depth of field.
The 2.8 version of EEVEE should be able to render the sequence for the video with the content shown in the viewport, but I'm afraid that multiple scenes will not have independent post-effects and background images.

Anyway, can multiple scenes have their own background images?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background images are part of UI data, that means they are saved along with user interface information withing the blend file, as such they cannot be different per scene, because UI data is saved once per file only.

As a side note you can also notice that if you disable the *Load UI* option when opening a file, background images will be gone.

They can still be controlled on a per-viewport basis, though, so two different 3D scene views can have different visible images, but the list will show the same datablocks.

Blender 2.8 post production effects and settings will probably be part of scene or even layer data, as such they have nothing to do with background image settings and can be independent per scene, as far as I know. Nothing is written in stone yet.

You could try using *Empty* objects as images as an alternative.

Comment: Wooow, Thanks.
As you say, custom layouts, not scenes, could have separate background images.
Actually doing scene editing with the custom layout feature is somewhat less intuitive, but anyway, it works as I want.
Thank you very much.

Comment: By the way, can you display an image on an empty object? What is the specific method?

Comment: After getting the answer, I used custom layouts for each scene for a few hours.
And i realized that the concept of scene-layout dependency can be changed by my view of value.
In the case of Blender, the scene belongs to the layout.
Switching scenes through a custom layout is not awkward at all.
Thanks to you, I learned something new again today.

Comment: And I figured out how to use an empty with an image.
At the bottom of the Create Empty Objects menu was the image option.

Comment: Yes, you can use empties with images. There is an option in *User Preferences > Editing > Global Scene* that will allow you to have different scenes open at the same time in different windows.

Comment: Oh yhea,
that is an option i didn't known.
But i like unchecked, because background images is belong to layout.